# How do I fetch the user currently logged into the OS on the client computer, using VueJS, NUXT and NODEjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

My apologies if this is a duplicate, but I have not found the magic combination of words to pull my answer out of Google.

I have tried placing the following code in the script section of the page, in nuxtServerInit, in my actions as 'setUser' and in a middleware file.  What gets returned each time is the current SERVER user.

as written in pages/index.vue:

```
<script>
import os from 'os'

export default {
  fetch({ store }) {
    const currentUser = os.userInfo().username
    const user = JSON.stringify(currentUser)
    console.log(user)
  }
```

I have also tried it as a method, called on mount:

```
<script>
import os from 'os'

export default {
mounted() {
this.fetchUser()
},
methods: {
fetchUser() {
    const currentUser = os.userInfo().username
    const user = JSON.stringify(currentUser)
    this.$store.dispatch('setUser', user)
}
}
```

as written in nuxtServerInit:

```
import os from 'os'

nuxtServerInit = ({commit}, context) => {
    const currentUser = os.userInfo().username
    const user = JSON.stringify(currentUser)
    commit('setUser', user)
}
```

Each bit of code works to get me a user, but it is always the server user.

Is it even possible to get the client OS User with Vuejs?

Thank You

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to access the information of a remote user using this web application? For example in the case of a site like https://stackoverflow.com, when you visited https://stackoverflow.com, the site would be able to see your OS user information?

Comment: essentially yes, I am trying to get the local user pulled into my web app

Comment: A Nuxt.js web application would be hosted on a server that would be remote to a user accessing it through the web. It would be an immense security issue if websites could access OS level information, file system, etc. Maybe this will help answer some general questions regarding what you could access via a web application https://superuser.com/questions/470348/how-much-information-can-websites-get-about-your-browser-pc

Comment: the app I am developing will only be accessible from the LAN, not over the web.  I want to be able to secure the information in the software, but in a way that I don't need to create users in the app, but  use the authenticated users on my companies Windows Server Domain.

Comment: You could try looking into LDAP if you have windows active directory set up

Comment: For reference you would use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone who commented.

I am marking this question as answered as, I have gone in a different direction after more study. And realizing this isn't the solution I was looking for.

comment #3 on my question pretty much sums up why the change in direction.